# How to get PHP to include a data URI (without turning on allow_url_include)?

Tags: php, data-uri

In my PHP setup, I have `allow_url_include` set to `FALSE` and I'm happy to keep it that way for security reasons.

When I want to

```
include 'https://example.com/path/to/include.php'; // <= THIS WON'T WORK
```

I can use:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/include.php'; // <= BUT THIS WILL
```

So far, so good.

---

Right now, however, I am experimenting with ways to create and then `include` *virtual files* in PHP at runtime.

I wondered if there might be something in PHP equivalent to javascript's `URL.createObjectURL()`, after which I discovered that PHP can read `data:` URIs.

Which sounds promising... but ***because*** I have `allow_url_include` set to `FALSE`, PHP tells me it cannot `include` a URI beginning with `data:`:

> ***Warning:*** `include(): data://` wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by `allow_url_include=0`

So, instead of:

```
include 'data:application/x-php;base64,ZnVuY3Rpb24gdGVzdDIoKSB7ZWNobyAnVGhpcyB0ZXN0IGZ1bmN0aW9uIDIgaXMgd29ya2luZy4nO30gdGVzdDIoKTs=';
```

I have to use `file_get_contents` and `eval` like this:

```
$Test_Function = file_get_contents('data:application/x-php;base64,ZnVuY3Rpb24gdGVzdDIoKSB7ZWNobyAnVGhpcyB0ZXN0IGZ1bmN0aW9uIDIgaXMgd29ya2luZy4nO30gdGVzdDIoKTs=');

eval("$Test_Function");
```

The latter approach **works**, but (not least because it's slow) I don't want to use `eval()` unless I absolutely have to.

Is there any way I can get PHP to `include` the `data:` URI, *without* turning on `allow_url_include`?

---

**Note 1:**

You may be curious as to what I've base-64 encoded here:

`ZnVuY3Rpb24gdGVzdDIoKSB7ZWNobyAnVGhpcyB0ZXN0IGZ1bmN0aW9uIDIgaXMgd29ya2luZy4nO30gdGVzdDIoKTs=`

It's simply the following:

```
function test2() {echo 'This test function 2 is working.';} test2();
```

---

**Note 2:**

When I first tried to create a Data URI (long before I posted here) I made a mistake with the percentage-encoding, invalidating the Data URI.

I tried base-64-encoding the Data URI instead (which worked), after which I didn't go back to the original percentage-encoded Data URI to figure out where I'd gone wrong.

But, it's important to note that there's **no reason** (apart from obfuscation) to use base-64 encoding in the Data URI ***at all***.

The following percentage-encoded Data URI is functionally identical:

```
data:application/x-php,function%20test2%28%29%20%7Becho%20%27This%20test%20function%202%20is%20working.%27%3B%7D%20test2%28%29%3B
```

---

**Note 3:**

Although, as yet, I've had no success in using `include` on a **Data URI** while `allow_url_include` remains set to `FALSE`, I thought I would compare:

1. writing a string and running `eval()` on that string to execute it
2. creating a file and running `include` on that file

A **test** consisted of running one of the processes above 10,000 times.
Rather than running a single test once, I ran a set of 6 tests consecutively.
Overall, I ran 5 sets.

That comes to 5 sets of 6 tests of 10,000 processes.

**In conclusion:**

- running `eval()` is (often but not always) **just over 10 times slower** than simply declaring and executing a function.
- creating, writing and saving file, and then running `include` on that file is **over 1000 times slower** than declaring and executing a function.
- the average time to declare and execute a simple function (from a sample of 60,000) was  `0.000002194s`
- the average time to run `eval()` on the same simple function (from a sample of 60,000) was  `0.00009262s`

Consequently, any string which took `eval()` as much as 100 times as long to parse and execute, would **still** only take *less than a single one hundredth of a second* (`< 0.01s`) to complete.

So... if I can't find any way to `include` a **Data URI**, I'll go with `eval()` since, despite being over 10 times slower than the normal speed of PHP , it's still pretty blazing.

---

Here (for the sake of completeness) are the results (in seconds) from the tests in **Note 3**:

### Set 1

#### PHP Script (Control) (x 10000)

- 0.0083s
- 0.0079s
- 0.0080s
- 0.0082s
- 0.0082s
- 0.0088s
- **0.0082s** *(Average)*

#### Eval Test (x 10000)

- 0.0881s
- 0.0928s
- 0.0996s
- 0.1023s
- 0.1420s
- 0.1244s
- **0.1082s** *(Average)*

#### Create File Test (x 10000)

- 12.8188s
- 15.3593s
- 17.8400s
- 13.7488s
- 28.2703s
- 26.3024s
- **19.0566s** *(Average)*

### Set 2

#### PHP Script (Control) (x 10000)

- 0.0137s
- 0.0135s
- 0.0124s
- 0.0161s
- 0.0130s
- 0.0133s
- **0.0137s** *(Average)*

#### Eval Test (x 10000)

- 0.1361s
- 0.1347s
- 0.0947s
- 0.0909s
- 0.1067s
- 0.1839s
- **0.1245s** *(Average)*

#### Create File Test (x 10000)

- 10.9942s
- 13.8902s
- 19.4267s
- 29.3531s
- 24.4923s
- 21.0390s
- **19.8659s** *(Average)*

### Set 3

#### PHP Script (Control) (x 10000)

- 0.0147s
- 0.0189s
- 0.0178s
- 0.0164s
- 0.0165s
- 0.0180s
- **0.0171s** *(Average)*

#### Eval Test (x 10000)

- 0.1436s
- 0.1421s
- 0.1675s
- 0.1977s
- 0.2570s
- 0.2749s
- **0.1971s** *(Average)*

#### Create File Test (x 10000)

- 17.8473s
- 13.0513s
- 12.8365s
- 17.9243s
- 21.5655s
- 24.1693s
- **17.8990s** *(Average)*

### Set 4

#### PHP Script (Control) (x 10000)

- 0.0195s
- 0.0207s
- 0.0222s
- 0.0192s
- 0.0200s
- 0.0204s
- **0.0203s** *(Average)*

#### Eval Test (x 10000)

- 0.2109s
- 0.2040s
- 0.2061s
- 0.1895s
- 0.2305s
- 0.2318s
- **0.2121s** *(Average)*

#### Create File Test (x 10000)

- 20.9385s
- 17.7350s
- 27.2538s
- 21.9894s
- 27.6480s
- 20.2680s
- **22.6388s** *(Average)*

### Set 5

#### PHP Script (Control) (x 10000)

- 0.0259s
- 0.0609s
- 0.0556s
- 0.0695s
- 0.0498s
- 0.0406s
- **0.0504s** *(Average)*

#### Eval Test (x 10000)

- 0.4123s
- 0.3235s
- 0.2588s
- 0.2810s
- 0.2172s
- 0.2132s
- **0.2843s** *(Average)*

#### Create File Test (x 10000)

- 14.9768s
- 13.9306s
- 26.4742s
- 26.1288s
- 35.6069s
- 23.1933s
- **23.3851s** *(Average)*

Comment: Why don't you want to use `eval()` for this?

Comment: `eval()` is dangerous if the argument contains dynamic data. But so is `include()` if the data URL contains dynamic data. They're practically equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar - because, if I understand correctly, (and I concede I may not) `eval` is: 1) many times slower than `include`; and 2)  it requires a parser to start up, which then 3) circumvents the `opcache`... and, in this scenario, speed optimisation is crucially important to me.

Comment: Can't you just do `ini_set('allow_url_include', 'On');` before process and `ini_set('allow_url_include', 'Off');` after?

Comment: Thanks, @Justinas. I tried this. Unfortunately when I add these three lines: Line 1: `print_r(ini_get('allow_url_include')); // 0 ` (as expected), Line 2: `ini_set('allow_url_include', true);` and then Line 3: `print_r(ini_get('allow_url_include')); // 0` (as if Line 2 made no change at all).

Comment: @Justinas - and the same if I try `ini_set('allow_url_include', 'On');` or `ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on');` or `ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);` instead of `ini_set('allow_url_include', true);`.

Comment: I don't get your reasoning at all, you want to include files from an external source but you want to keep `allow_url_include` for "security reasons" disabled?

Comment: What you are looking for is essentially a way to circumvent `allow_url_include`. If you can do it, then an attacker can do too. So why keep it disabled?

Comment: @marco-a - It's not the `include` part of `allow-url-include` that's the problem. It's the `url` part.

Comment: @Rounin Sorry, I re-read your question. I misunderstood what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rounin What about saving the result of the `file_get_contents` call to a tmpfs and *then* include that temporary file?

Comment: I wonder whether the optimizations you say would be missing with `eval` would be done for a dynamically-generated data URL.

Answer (score 2):

One idea that comes to my mind is to save the resulting code in a temporary file (in a [tmpfs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html)) and then `include`ing it.

```
$Test_Function = file_get_contents('data:application/x-php;base64,ZnVuY3Rpb24gdGVzdCgpe2VjaG8nVGhpcyB0ZXN0IGRhdGEgdXJsIGZ1bmN0aW9uIDEgaXMgd29ya2luZy4nO30gdGVzdCgpOw==');

file_put_contents("/mnt/tempfs/<name>.php", "<?php\n$Test_Function");

include "/mnt/tempfs/<name>.php";
```

Regarding performance:

> The tmpfs facility allows the creation of filesystems whose contents
>   reside in virtual memory.  Since the files on such filesystems
>   typically reside in RAM, file access is extremely fast.

Comment: This is the beginning of a good idea, I think, but over-complicates it - if you're saving to `tmpfs`, you don't need the base64 part at all, just the original code string.

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah. I just thought this solution would satisfy OP's needs.

Comment: Thank you for this @marco-a. I'll need to verify what I'm supposed to be doing here. If I execute this script: `$myTestFunction = 'function test6() {echo \'This test function 6 is working.\';} test6();'; mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mnt'); mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mnt/tmpfs'); file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mnt/tmpfs/my-test-function.php', "<?php\n\n$myTestFunction\n\n?>"); include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mnt/tmpfs/my-test-function.php';` then it works. But all I'm doing here is creating a real file on the server and then including it.

Answer (score 2):

I smell an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have looked at `eval` and `data:` URIs as possible solutions to a particular problem, and found drawbacks of both, but not gone back to the original problem statement.

From various comments, we can define the problem as finding a mechanism which:

1. Can execute arbitrary dynamic code
2. Has similar parsing performance to a normal `include`
3. Will allow the code to be cached in OpCache
4. Does not require security to be loosened elsewhere

You say that `eval` fails on point 2 (because it starts a new parser) and point 3 (because there is no key for OpCache to use).

You have identified that `data:` URIs fail on point 4 (because they require `allow_url_include`), but I suspect they also fail on point 2 (because base64 decoding is a non-trivial overhead), and point 3 (because OpCache does not support caching arbitrary streams; I believe it only supports file paths and PHAR contents)

As [suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195319/157957) a better overall solution is to write your code to a "real" file, using an in-memory file system such as `tmpfs` for performance. This meets all four criteria above, because as far as PHP is concerned it's the same as any other source file; the only extra overhead is the I/O speed of writing a file to the virtual file system.

The key optimisation will be to ensure that you track when the dynamic content has changed, generating a unique file path from some kind of revision ID or a hash of the string. This enables two things:

1. You can skip writing a file that already exists on disk, saving I/O time
2. OpCache will be able to cache the contents of this file and reuse it, and you can be confident the correct code is run even if you set `opcache.validate_timestamps` to false

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write your `data:` php://memory ([read about wrappers here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)). Since it acts like regular file there, you could maybe include it?

Comment: I suspect this will also be treated as a URL, since it has the format `url-scheme://`

Comment: Thanks @matek997, I did some experiments based on this suggestion (which, if nothing else, helped me learn a lot more about `I/O streams` and `wrappers` in PHP). What I found was that if I set up the following: `$myStream = fopen('php://memory', 'rw+'); $myTestFunction = 'function test5() {echo \'This test function 5 is working.\';} test5();'; fwrite($myStream, $myTestFunction); rewind($myStream);` then... 1) `include 'php://memory';` yields nothing and 2) `include $myStream;` yields: `include(Resource id #9): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. [1/2]

Comment: The only success I found was with: `echo stream_get_contents($myStream);` which then echoes back the contents of the string variable `$myTestFunction` which I wrote to `$myStream`. If I wanted to proceed from there, I'd still need to use `eval()`. Nevertheless thanks for the suggestion. Even though I can't use `php://memory` in this situation, it's still introduced me to a whole new area of PHP. [2/2]